# PDO foreach printing out a single entry from wrong column

Tags: mysql, pdo, foreach, fetchall

Sorry for the awkward title, I have a query that is supposed to return all the comments that have the value `1` in the `blog` column.

The table is made up of three columns:

`CommentID` `Comments` `Blog`

At the moment the query is returning all the comments with `blog` value of `1` however it is also printing out the `CommentID` of the most recently entered comment along with the value `1` (the value `1` is still printed even if the `WHERE` value is changed from `1` to `2`).

Here is my query:

```
  public function getComments($blog) {
    $conn = $this->dbConnection->Connection();
    $sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT `Comment` FROM comments WHERE Blog = ?");
    $sth->bindValue (1, $blog);
    $sth->execute();
    $result = $sth->fetchAll();
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        print $row['Comment'] . "\n";
    }
    $conn = $this->dbConnection->closeConnection();
  }
```

I am looking it just to print out the contents of `Comment WHERE Blog = 1`, what is causing my problem?

Comment: Do not open and close connection to DB in the every function! You will kill your DB server. Connect **once** per application and use this **single** connection over all scripts involved.

Comment: Thanks for that, been noted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some other code in your PHP file that does print extra numbers.  Check it out.
The code you posted here intended to print the Comment field only (though it may contain some extra numbers as well)

Comment: Embarrassingly this was indeed the case, I had just done a quick check using find for `print_r` and `print` but didn't realise there was an `echo` burred in one of the queries!